# Python strings assignment

Tags: python, string, list

I know that Python strings are immutable.
I was wondering if there was a more memory efficient in doing this (grid is a 2d list) instead of having to create a whole other list and copying everything over.

```
def replace(grid, firstchar, secondchar):
    for row in range(len(grid)):
        for col in range(len(grid[row])):
            if grid[row][col] == firstchar: 
                grid[row][col] = secondchar
```

Tried implementing .join()

Comment: You're not creating another list, you're modifying the list in place.

Comment: the current code does not work since strings are immutable in python

Comment: It's not mutating strings, it's assigning to a list element.

Comment: It would be mutating strings if `grid` were a list of strings rather than a 2d list of strings.

Comment: Please post a [mre] showing how you create `grid`.

Comment: Provide an example of what `grid` looks like. If it's really a list of lists of strings, you have no problem. If it's a list of strings, then you can't replace a *character* in one string with another character; you need to replace the entire string with a new string (`grid[row] = grid[row].replace(firstchar, secondchar)`, e.g.).

Comment: grid = [[]]
    for line in fileptr:
        grid.append(line)

Comment: That's not a 2d list; that's just a list containing an empty list followed by a bunch of strings, e.g., `[[], "foo", "bar"]`

Comment: You *could* do something like `grid = [list(line) for line in fileptr]` to get `[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]`, which should allow your `replace` function to work. Whether that's better than simply storing `["foo", "bar"]` and using `str.replace` to generate new strings as necessary depends a lot on your actual use case.